# Remotely debug system framework

Tags: android, android-source, android-debug

I would like to debug a system framework running on an Android device.

In particular, `GpsLocationProvider` sometimes stops for a while, and I would like to know what it is doing. I found the class contains a `android.os.Handler` that gets messages posted to it, to communicate between threads. Sometimes it takes minutes between a message is sent, and `Handler.handleMessage` is called. I interpret that the thread belonging to the `Handler`'s `Looper` is busy.

I would like to attach a debugger, pause that thread, and see what's currently executing. Alternatively, somehow get a traceback of that thread. Is there any way to do that?

I tried creating an Android Studio project from the source tree with `development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh`, but I'm not sure how to proceed from there. In case it matters, the (legacy) device is running Android 6.

I've also just discovered `debuggerd`. I call `logcat -s GpsLocationProvider` to find the corresponding PID, and feed it to `debuggerd`, both with and without `-b` argument. However, this only gives be a backtrace into native code. I don't see any java code there.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, if you have the respective Android API version in your AndroidStudio (installed through SDK Manager), you can install debug variant of your app on the device and then put breakpoints inside Android's code.

This way you can pause the execution of the component's code and see what it's doing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. It seems the code is running in a system service, will it still work?

Comment: You'll need to try that to see. I honestly don't remember how it all works from the top of my head, but I remember that I set breakpoints in some Android classes.